# Find end of iterator without access to vector

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Without having access to the vector, is there a way to determine if the iterator is reaching the end of the vector by using just the iterator?

For example with the following function how do I loop through iter:

```
list<int>::iterator foo(vector<list<int>>::iterator iter, int value)
{


}
```

Comment: Not unless the container has a known end-of-container value like a null terminator in a c string.

Comment: Ever wonder why you always see these things in pairs ?

Comment: No there's no such possibility using standard iterators. That's why all standard functions takes two iterators to define the range. Which of course also allows you to use a sub-range of the full container.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize there was supposed to be a global vector in the file. I guess I'll keep the question listed here anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  This is like getting a pointer to an array without getting its size.  Unless there is a sentinel element (like a null character in a c-string) there is no way to know where the container stops.

You need to either take a reference to the vector so you can iterate it or have a end iterator passed to the function as well so you have a bound for the loop.